# Expanding UiView Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I am trying to implement the following animation in my swift iOS app. There is currently a `UIView` at the bottom of my screen with the following properties :

```
  let containerView : UIView = {
    let this = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 600,150))
    this.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    this.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    this.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: (69/255.0), green: (209/255.0), blue: (153/255.0), alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    this.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    return this
}()
```

Inside, there is an imageView, a couple buttons and other components. The `containerView` also has a blur effect implemented on it. When the user presses on it, I want the view to move upwards until it reaches the top of the screen. At the same time I want the borders to be drawn, to fill the whole screen, as shown in the outline below. I also want to apply the blur effect as an animation along with the border to the whole screen. Finally, when this animation is finished, I want my collectionView to fade into the space which has been created within  the expanded view. I have next to zero experience with animating views in Swift, however these are the ideas which I had :

1. Apply a movement animation which moves the top of the view from the current position to the top of the screen.
2. During this process, gradually fade in the expanded view so that it appears as if the view itself is expanding.
3. Finally, when both animations complete, fade in the collectionView (this should be the easiest part).

However, I'm not sure if my way of thinking is correct, particularly when it comes to drawing the borders and background dynamically doing the animation. I am looking for some advice on how to approach this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take outlet of `heightConstraint` of the view which you want to animate.
Make `heightConstraint.constant = 0` initially.

On click do something like this.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
       self.heightConstraint.constant = YOURMAXVALUE
// perform fade in out tasks here 

        self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    };
```

or you can do this with topConstriant also..
Initially set topConstaint such that view will go down.
And then animate like this to see effects